# Recording on iPhone from stereo line-in

Tags: ios, audio, recording

I'm looking for a way to perform relatively high quality stereo line-in recording on iPhone. Unusual and third-party hardware is acceptable, but jailbreak is not. I am aware of the following options:

[Griffin iMic](http://store.griffintechnology.com/imic) paired with Apple's [Lightning to USB Camera Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD821ZM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter)

- Pros: Well-reviewed, USB interface.
- Cons: Lightning to USB Camera Adapter is not supported on iPhone.

[Blue Mikey Digital](http://bluemic.com/mikey_digital/)

- Pros: Works with iPhone.
- Cons: Requires Lightning adapter, line-in quality [reportedly poor](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/reviews/entry/blue-microphones-mikey-digital/).

Neither of those satisfies my requirements. Is there some workaround I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out some of the electric-guitar-interfaces.  For example, the [Line 6 Sonic Port Channel Audio Interface](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CS4L7DK) has a stereo 1/8" input jack available. On the pricier side though.

Comment: A colleague referred me to the same device. I agree that it solves my need. I'll delete my my answer and accept yours, but please consider editing it to include the product name as a reference for others.

Comment: @Justin Good idea, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

For a cheaper solution using products that are available (at least as of the time of this writing in August 2022), reportedly the [Behringer U-Control UCA202](https://www.behringer.com/product.html?modelCode=P0484) will work with an iPhone when combined with a cheap USB to Lightning adapter.